# C# dynamically create labels inside a Panel while getting values from XMLfile

Tags: c#, xml

XML file "XMLFile1.xml"

```
<website>
    <productlist>
        <a>dynnaplatka</a>
        <b>pamet</b>
        <c>procesor</c>
    </productlist>
</website>
```

The problem is that when I run the solution the code adds 1 label with text dynnaplatkapametprocesor instead of 3 labels with text dynnaplatka,pamet,procesor

I watch my code for 1 hour and i can't see the problem to fix it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));
    XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("website/productlist");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
    {
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = node.InnerText;
        lbl.CssClass = "Labels";
        lbl.ID = node.InnerText;               
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method `doc.SelectNodes("website/productlist");` select the `<productlist>` node, not its childs.

To select all child nodes you need this XPath expression : `doc.SelectNodes("website/productlist/*");`